# "Could not autowire. No beans of type... found" with Simple project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-data-jpa

I downloaded the simple [JPA Spring Boot tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) and it worked just fine. However, when I attempt to replicate this simple behavior in my own test project, I get a "could not autowire" error on the bean injection in my Application.demo() method that returns a CommandLineRunner. The project is so barebones I don't even know what to submit but here's the POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

And the application.

```
package com.example;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    //errors with: "Could not autowire. No beans of 'SimpRepository' type found"
    public CommandLineRunner demo(SimpRepository repository) {
        return (args) -> {

        };
    }
}
```

And the Repository service:

```
package com.example;
public interface SimpRepository extends CrudRepository<Simp, Long> {

}
```

for the following entity:

```
package com.example;
@Entity
public class Simp {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String value;

    public Simp(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post the error, not just paraphrase it. You also need to specify the packages all your classes are in.

Comment: Can you try with @Repository on top of your SimpRepository interface.

Comment: @cody123 Adding the annotation does fix the problem. But I am curious as to why it works in the original demo project without it

Comment: Answer is already provided by metacubed . You can upvote comment if it helped you in anyway.

Comment: The example works fine for me (I made a new project and copied your code). The only issue I'm noticing is that you should have a default no-arg constructor for your entity, but even without a constructor the repository is injectable. Make sure all classes are within the same package (or a subpackage of `TestApplication`)  and make sure you've built your code properly.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A couple of possibilities here.

You need to add the `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"your.pkg.here"})` to the `TestApplication`. This tells Spring Data to look for your repository classes under the specified package. If the repository package name is the same as the `TestApplication`, you can skip the `basePackages` part.

Similarly, if your `TestApplication` and `SimpRepository` are not in the same package, you need to add a `@ComponentScan` with the list of all relevant packages.

Comment: This sunds reasonable, and for the record they are in the same package, but I'm trying to figure out why it works in the Spring Demo project I posted a link to, but doesn't work for the project I posted. Both seem to be functionally identical but I know there must be some subtle difference between the two. The demo project's files are in the same package as well, and there is no reference to EnableJpaRepositories there

Comment: @IcedDante hmm, that tutorial explicitly says that you need a `@EnableJpaRepositories` only if your package is different. However, I have always needed to add the annotation regardless.

Answer (score 4):

I missed a simple `@Component` for the class. This could be one basic problem.

Answer (score 3):

Add a simple `@Repository` annotation above your repository class and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue [IDEA-271551](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-271551) just opened with JetBrains. Please upvote it.

In my case I resolved(not actual resolution,but workaround) it by explicitly annotating my repository interface with **@Repository** stereotype.

However, I also noticed that later if I again remove the annotation the IDE no longer complains.

Strange, but it did happen in my case.

Comment: I also faced the same issue and upvoted

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add
"  annotationProcessor <<<-libs.mapstructprocessor->>> "
among Dependencies
in build.gradle.
It was fixed when I added it.

```
  dependencies {
    
    implementation  libs.mapstruct
    implementation  libs.mapstructprocessor
    implementation  libs.lombok

    annotationProcessor libs.lombok
    annotationProcessor libs.mapstructprocessor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a quite a flat package structure (notice that I don't have the usual com.x.y.z in my application) hence met this issue. Following `@ComponentScan` fixed the issue:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"services", "views", "database"})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

You don't need this explicit definitions if your Spring `Application` class too is in the same package hierarchy.